# Remove or replace +1 from the string : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, masking

I am applying phone number masking on a phone number. I want to make sure that there is no +1 in the beginning and if there is remove it. What would be the best way to do that?

```html
self.phoneNumberMasking = function (data) {
        if (data != "" && data != null) {
            var x = data.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
            data = '+1(' + x[1] + ')' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
            return data;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Since I am not removing or replacing +1 in the above code, it is adding another 1 when I try to apply the mask on a number that already has +1 in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if the input starts with `"+1"`, and, if so, remove it before further processing:

```js
function validate (input) {
  let str = input.trim();
  if (str.startsWith('+1')) str = str.slice(2);
  str = str.replaceAll(/\D/g, '');
  if (str.length !== 10) throw new Error('Invalid input');
  return `+1(${str.slice(0, 3)})${str.slice(3, 6)}-${str.slice(6)}`;
}

const inputs = [
  '+11234567890',
  '1234567890',
  '+1 123.456.7890',
  '+1 123 456 7890',
  '1 123 456 7890',
];

for (const input of inputs) {
  try {
    const result = validate(input);
    console.log(input, result);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(input, err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: The code in this answer doesn't validate some other assumptions about the input string, but those aren't asked about in the question either.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `replace()` you just need a better regex like
`/(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/`
This will ignore the `'+1'` at the beginning due to the `$` it basically captures only the last 10 digits (in the proper grouping).
[A good tool to use for debugging is regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/yaV3tZ/2)

```js
let phoneNumberMasking = function(data) {
  if (data != "" && data != null) {
    var x = data.match(/(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/);
    data = '+1(' + x[1] + ')' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
    return data;
  }
  return data;
}
console.log(phoneNumberMasking('2345678910'))
console.log(phoneNumberMasking('+1(234) 567 - 8910'))
console.log(phoneNumberMasking('+1-234-567-8910'))
console.log(phoneNumberMasking('area code:[234] phone number: 567_8910'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified your 'replace regex' to also replace the "+1" from the beginning of the string.

Please check.

```
self.phoneNumberMasking = function (data) {
        if (data != "" && data != null) {
         
            // var x = data.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
        
            var x = data.replace(/(^\+1|\D)/g, '').match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
            data = '+1(' + x[1] + ')' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
            return data;
        }
        return data;
    }
```